# React project returning Source map error: Error: request failed with status 403

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, bootstrap-4

Getting error Source map error: Error: request failed with status 403 in my console in my react project

I suspect that this is because of the UseEffect not working correctly in displaying the list in my API response

The API returns the response as a list as expected but when its time to iterate through the elements in the list returned from the API that's where the problem originates

[image: error screenshot of browser console here]

here's my code below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import AwardCard from "./AwardCard";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import {GET_ALL_AWARDS_URL} from "../../../utils/constants";

const InitialDashboardScreen = () => {
    const [allAwards, setAllAwards] = useState([]);
    let dynamicList = []


    useEffect(() => {

        axios
            .get(GET_ALL_AWARDS_URL)
            .then(({data}) => {

                console.log(data)
                const allAwardsArray = data

                const tempAllAwardsArray = allAwards

                allAwardsArray.map((i) => {
                    tempAllAwardsArray.push(i)
                    return tempAllAwardsArray
                })
                setAllAwards(tempAllAwardsArray)

                dynamicList = tempAllAwardsArray
                console.log("next line returns the data from the API as an array successfully");
                console.log("dynamicList >> ", dynamicList);
                console.log("allAwards >> ", allAwards);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.info(error))

    }, [allAwards])


    return (
        <div style={{}}>
            <hr/>
        
            <p className="text-center">
      
                <hr/>
            </p>
            {allAwards.map((data, index) => {
                return <AwardCard key={index} data={data}/>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default InitialDashboardScreen;
```

Here's the code for the card

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";


const AwardCard = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Card className="shadow border" style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
        <Card.Header style={{fontWeight: 'bolder', color: 'black'}}>{data.pubDate}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title className="p-1" style={{marginLeft: '-8px', color: 'black'}}>{data.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
            <span style={{fontWeight: 'bolder'}}>Category:</span> {data.category}
          </Card.Text>
          <Card.Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
            <span style={{fontWeight: 'bolder'}}>Description:</span> {data.description}
          </Card.Text>
          <Card.Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
            <span style={{fontWeight: 'bolder'}}></span> {(data.content).substring(37,250) + "(..)"}
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary" href={data.link} target='_blank'>More Detail</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div style={{border: '1px solid rgba(45,45,45,0.2)', marginBottom: '1.5em', width: '80%', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight:'auto'}}  />
    </>
  );
};

export default AwardCard;
```

Comment: `leftSide` object and key `current` are not present in the code you share. You need to take a look at a function called handleResize in the `Dashboard.js` component on `line 44`, there you will find the root of the issue and more information, probably your data is been loaded correctly but after loading, it is falling while calling an extra component that does not have the required data to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition like the below:

```
{allAwards.length && allAwards.map((data, index) => {
  return <AwardCard key={index} data={data}/>;
})}
```

Initially, allAwards array is empty. So to avoid mapping through the empty array, need to provide a length check.

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion did 'not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).